# Как лучше организовать иерархию классов

Tags: ооп, kotlin

У меня есть абстрактный ImageFilter такого содержания:

```
abstract class ImageFilter {
    internal abstract val size: Int
    fun applyForImage(image: BmpImage) {
        //тут используется size для вычисления границ
        //где-то тут вызывается applyForOnePixel(data)
        //...
    }

    abstract fun applyForOnePixel(data: Array<Array<RGBColor>>): RGBColor
}
```

Реализовать класс наследник нет проблемы, однако, чтобы вызвать applyForImage нужно обязательно создавать instance, например, таким образом

```
GrayscaleFilter().applyForImage(img)
```

Однако хочется делать это так

```
GrayscaleFilter.applyForImage(img)
```

Я понимаю, что нужно использовать companion object, но как заставить наследников реализовывать applyForOnePixel и указывать size, если внутри compaion object'a нельзя использовать abstract?

Comment: Мое предположение. Вам бы статический метод сделать из `applyForImage`. Можно в абстрактном ругаться исключением типа "Не реализовано", а в наследниках перекрывать метод

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
abstract class Foo {

    abstract val s: String

    fun print(i: Int) {
        println("$s$i")
    }
}


class Bar {
    companion object : Foo() {
        override val s = "Bar"
    }
}

class Baz {
    companion object : Foo() {
        override val s = "Baz"
    }
}

fun main() {
    Bar.print(1) // Bar1
    Baz.print(2) // Baz2
}
```

Можно упростить и сделать сами классы синглтонами и наследниками абстрактного класса

```
object Bar : Foo() {
    override val s = "Bar"
}

object Baz : Foo() {
    override val s = "Baz"
}
```